# Alternative to SQLite

Tags: android, database

I am using eclipse to create android app right now. I am confused on what database should I use to create the app. My question, is it okay to use MYSQL/PHP as a database to my android app? Using java as my language? Sorry for asking this, I am truly newbie and don't want to use the SQLite.

Comment: this question does not even feature any reason, why you don't want to use it.

Comment: i actually tried the sqlite but i cant. And also, I researched about it, it says it needs effort and time consuming, and prone to errors(?) sorry for my english.

Comment: consider learning SQLite (which is similar to mySQL) - or use Firebase. the amount of down-votes and close-votes within short time is because: questions asking for suggestions are considered off-topic on here. besides, all the object relational mapping suggested in the answers below, that is SQlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

At first I would suggest using Android Studio instead of Eclipse. The Android Developer Tools (ADT) aren't supported anymore since 2015 and Android Studio has many cool features which will make your life much easier developing Android Apps.

The other thing is why don't you want to use SQLite? Of course you could connect a MySQL database to your app. But this requires network calls, an API (which you would provide via PHP I guess) etc.
Instead you could simply use SQLite locally on your device. I would suggest having a look at [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as this is one of the easiest solutions working with databases in android in my opinion.

If you have any further questions feel free to reply!

Comment: Thanks @Phil . Actually my problem regarding SQLite is I cant access or can't get the db file inside /data/data/ [file explorer] using my device [not rooted], so I decided to find another database alternative to SQLite to make my 'database coding' much easier and faster (if ever)

Comment: I'm not a big friend of SQLite too and also started my first database experiences with MySQL. But since Room Library it has been so much easier and there are really good tutorials. Do you really need the actual file or do you just want to have a look into the database at runtime and maybe manipulate some of its values?

Comment: If the last one is your desire then you could have a look at Facebooks Stetho. It is a really useful tool debugging your app and look into databases, shared preferences etc. (see http://facebook.github.io/stetho/)

Comment: and about Room Persistence Library, is it similar or connected in SQLite?

Comment: Under the hood, Room is SQLite. It just provides an abstraction layer helping you to get around some really annoying stuff of plain SQLite. If you follow the link I posted you can find some additional information, training guides and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL requires you to have it set up on a web server and the right way to connect to it is through API which increases complexity. It depends on your use case, if you want to store data on the client side its better practice to use SQLite or some other data persistent methods such as [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-java). If you choose to work with SQLite, there are plenty of ORMs out there which make your work easy, such as [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), [DBFlow](https://github.com/agrosner/DBFlow), [greenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO), etc. ORMs help you to work with your database more easily and facilitate the implementation of your database logic.